# Rails: How can I access the parent model of a new record's nested associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, callback

Suppose we have the standard Post & Comment models, with Post having `accepts_nested_attributes_for :commments` and `:autosave => true` set.

We can create a new post together with some new comments, e.g.:

```
@post = Post.new :subject => 'foo'
@post.comments.build :text => 'bar'
@post.comments.first # returns the new comment 'bar'
@post.comments.first.post # returns nil :(
@post.save # saves both post and comments simultaneously, in a transaction etc
@post.comments.first # returns the comment 'bar'
@post.comments.first.post # returns the post 'foo'
```

However, I need to be able to distinguish from within Comment (e.g. from its before_save or validation functions) between

1. this comment is not attached to a post (which is invalid)
2. this comment is attached to an *unsaved* post (which is valid)

Unfortunately, merely calling `self.post` from Comment doesn't work, because per above, it returns nil until after save happens. In a callback of course, I don't (and shouldn't) have access to @post, only to self of the comment in question.

So: how can I access the parent model of a new record's nested associations, from the perspective of that nested association model?

(FWIW, the actual sample I'm using this with allows people to create a naked "comment" and will then automatically create a "post" to contain it if there isn't one already. I've simplified this example so it's not specific to my code in irrelevant ways.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is strange that Rails does not let you do this. It also affects validations in the child model.

There's a ticket with much discussion and no resolution in the Rails bug tracker about this:

> [Nested attributes validations
>   circular
>   dependency](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1943-nested-attributes-validations-circular-dependency)

And a proposed resolution:

> [nested models: build should directly
>   assign the
>   parent](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/2815-nested-models-build-should-directly-assign-the-parent)

Basically, the deal is, the nested attributes code doesn't set the parent association in the child record.

There's some work-arounds mentioned in the second ticket I linked to.

Comment: How would it do it? You don't want to set the parent_id column, so you'd have to add some hidden properties on the child?

Comment: You can set an attribute (e.g. parent, children) without setting the requisite _ids. That's how it does nested model saving currently - it just has this flaw of not being recursive.

Comment: @Sai following the posted links, I can see this can be achieved using `inverse_of` option.

Comment: @elquimista having tried myself, the `inverse_of` does not help in this case.

Comment: @lulalala can you elaborate, how it doesn't help in your case?

Comment: @elquimista the back referencing is still `nil`.

Comment: @lulalala I can help you via tmate session if you want, otherwise can't help you much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. On the other hand, your validations shouldn't be failing, as the order of the transaction will create the post record before saving the comment.