# Custom validation: referencing parent association from model created by accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I need to validate presence of title only if type of question is 'select' or 'checkboxes':

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  attr_accessible :title

  validate :need_title?

  private
  def need_title?
     errors.add(:need_title, "")) if 
     ((question.type_of_answer == 'select' || question.type_of_answer == 'checkboxes') && title.blank?)
  end
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true

  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

But when I create object, I get this exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `type_of_answer' for nil:NilClass
```

Why `question` is `nil` in `Answer#need_title?` during validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you're creating question with nested answers. For the newly created answer its `question` association is `nil`. Here's an old question [addressing the root cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896014/rails-how-can-i-access-the-parent-model-of-a-new-records-nested-associations).

Here's how you can set up parent object with custom build method:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers do
    def build(*args)
      answer = super
      answer.question = self.proxy_owner
      answer
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

This should assign reverse association (from answer to question) when constructing new answers from nested attributes and your validator would get non nil `question` as it expects.

Comment: Thank you I solved this problem as described in this article [Nested attributes validations](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1943-nested-attributes-validations-circular-dependency). I tryed your variant, but it did not work. I does not know why, in `rails c` after build, parent present, but on validation I see the same error message.